# Salesforce developer Edition

Tags: managed-package, package

I am new salesforce developer and working on the existing developed app on the salesforce. (Developer edition from client)

Here we have a release org for development and testing and than we push the changes to the production org.

So now our company decided to buy a new licence for developing new apps so  which licence should we buy.

And how can partitioned that edition as a release org (sandbox) and than deploy to the client and what is the licence client need to buy for using our app.

We are running a company and want to start the  development on salesforce and sales the apps to different clients so would like to know a full process from development to deployment including licence for us and as well as for client

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You would need to be using Enterprise Edition or Performance Edition as these allow development of Apex code and also include Sandboxes which can be used for the development separate from the Test and Production environments. Devendra's answer really gives what you need to look at which is the ISV program for vendors supplying multiple clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Independent Software Vendor (ISV) program is for partners who want to build and sell apps.

Apps provide pre-written and packaged functionality intended to be sold to many different customers. Apps can be delivered through the AppExchange.

The following links would be helpful to start Partner Program with Salesforce.com

[Partner program](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/appvendors)

[ISV Force Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_intro.htm)